# Where can I download earlier versions of Oculus? I specifically need Oculus utilities 0.8 so as to use it on RiftCat

Tags: unity, oculus

I am trying to create a game using the Leap Motion, Oculus and Unity 5. I am using RiftCat to tether it to a mobile. But games built with Oculus versions 0.6 - 0.8 are allowed to be tethered. I have found the Oculus Runtime for 0.8 but I am not able to find the Oculus utilities package. Is there another way to do this? Can anybody provide a link where I can download the Oculus utilities 0.8 for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://developer3.oculus.com/downloads/

Check 'Game Engines' in a drop-down menu
and pick a desired version on the right :)

You should use the latest one

Comment: Hi , i still see versions like "0.1.3" and "0.1.2 beta" .Are these equivalent to v0.8 ? Are the versions in the drop down the only ones that will be available ? Thanks

Comment: There is no version of utlities like 0.8 or 0.6. Maybe you mean the SDK?

Comment: Im new to using oculus, so i have this oculus runtime v0.8 , what version of utilities do i need to download ?

Comment: you should download the latest for Unity5

Answer (score -2):

Always download the latest version from here: https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/game-engines/latest/concepts/unity-downloads/

This is the one that ypu need but uninstall previous ver. first.

Comment: 1. the question explicitly asked about OLDER versions, not the most current one. 2. the link doesn't even work. How did this answer get two upvotes in just 2 minutes?

Comment: The latest utils version works with all older versions. That's why she should download the latest.